# How to validate a web2py form submitted via AJAX?

Tags: python, ajax, forms, python-2.7, web2py

I'm trying to submit a form using web2py's `ajax` function as [explained in the book](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11/jquery-and-ajax#Ajax-form-submission), but using `FORM` instead of `SQLFORM` since I don't want the data to be stored in a database.

**ajax_test.html**

```
{{extend "layout.html"}}
<h2>Form</h2>
{{=form}}
<script>
  jQuery("#myform").submit(function() {
    ajax("{{=URL('ajax_test')}}",
         ["mytext"], "output");
    return false;
  });
</script>
<h2>Output</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Controller inside **default.py**:

```
def ajax_test():
    form = FORM(
        INPUT(_type="text", _name="mytext", _id="mytext",
              requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
        INPUT(_type="submit"),
        _id="myform"
    )

    if request.ajax:
        if form.accepts(request.vars, session):
            return DIV("Form submitted.")
        elif form.errors:
            return TABLE(*[TR(k, v) for k, v in form.errors.items()])
        else:
            return DIV("Couldn't check form.")

    return dict(form=form)
```

When the form is submitted (`request.ajax == True`), both `form.accepts` and `form.errors` return `False`. Even though I access user's input via `request.vars.mytext`, then I would need to validate it on my own instead of using web2py's capabilities.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass the `session` object to `form.accepts()`, it will automatically implement cross-site request forgery protection by adding a hidden `_formkey` field to the form. When the form is submitted, the value of this hidden field is compared with the value stored in the session, and the form is not accepted if the match fails.

There are two problems with your code. First, you only call `form.accepts` when there is an Ajax request, so the `_formkey` does not get generated and included in the original form. To correct that, try the following:

```
form.process()
if request.ajax:
    if form.accepted:
```

`form.process()` is just a shortcut for `form.accepts(request, session)`. Above, it is called even for the initial non-Ajax call when the form is created. This will generate the `_formkey` value and store it in the session.

Second, your Javascript code does not submit the whole form but only the `mytext` field, so the hidden `_formkey` value will not be posted back to the server. As a result, the form is not accepted (web2py does not display an error in this case, as such a failure would typically be the result of foul play).

I'm not sure it is documented, but the second argument to the `ajax()` function can instead be a jQuery selector, which will result in all form elements inside the selected element being serialized and submitted. So, try:

```
    ajax('{{=URL('ajax_test')}}', '#myform', 'output');
```

The `#myform` selector will result in the entire form being serialized, including the hidden fields included in the `form` object.

Comment: Hi Anthony thanks for the answer. I've changed the second argument to `"#myform"` but I'm getting the same result. I was aware about the `_formkey` hidden value, but for some reason it is not being generated. The HTML code for the form is `<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform" method="post"><input id="mytext" name="mytext" type="text" /><input type="submit" /></form>`. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see updated answer. You must process the form when it is initially created, so that code cannot be inside the `if request.ajax:` block.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.